# How Can I install `passenger-install-nginx-module` via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, rvm, dockerfile, passenger, confd

How Can I install `passenger-install-nginx-module` via Dockerfile?

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER hgkim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl build-essential libpq-dev advancecomp gcc libpcre3 \
    libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gifsicle jhead \
    jpegoptim libjpeg-progs optipng pngquant libzmq-dev libevent-dev python-dev \
    python-virtualenv python libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && virtualenv circus && /circus/bin/pip install circus-web==0.5 \
    && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime \
    && useradd -d /home/newbie -m -s /bin/bash newbie \
    && usermod -aG root newbie \
    && echo 'ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
    && curl -L -O http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/pngcrush/1.7.81/pngcrush-1.7.81.tar.gz \
    && tar xvzf pngcrush* \
    && cd pngcrush* \
    && make \
    && mv pngcrush /usr/local/bin/ \
    && cd / && curl -L https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/releases/download/v0.6.3/confd-0.6.3-linux-amd64 -o confd \
    && mv confd /usr/local/bin/confd && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/confd

USER newbie

RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3 \
    && \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable \
    && /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.1.0" \
    && /bin/bash -l -c "rvm use 2.1.0" \
    && echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > /home/newbie/.gemrc

ENV PATH /home/newbie/.rvm/bin:/home/newbie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/newbie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/newbie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:$PATH

RUN gem install passenger -v 4.0.55 \
    && rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module \
    --auto --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --auto-download --languages ruby

CMD bash
```

Above is my dockerfile.

I just want to setup passenger-nginx-module...

But I got error in last `RUN` instruction in Dockerfile

```
RUN gem install passenger -v 4.0.55 \
    && rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module \
    --auto --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --auto-download --languages ruby
```

First, install passenger,
Second, try to install nginx-module via `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` command.

But docker response this error

error:

```
Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.

Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

Although I just tried to command `rvmsudo`...

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

try replace RUN passenger-install-nginx-module by

```
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'passenger-install-nginx-module --auto-download --auto --prefix=/opt/nginx'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to automate the config/build process -- but why?   You know that the passenger-install-nginx-module downloads and compiles nginx from source right?

Why not just add the passenger apt repository and install it via apt-get?   So much easier.

[Passenger Debian Install Guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

What user2105103 said. You could also just use [passenger-docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
RUN passenger-install-nginx-module --auto-download --auto --prefix=/opt/nginx